# Possible to create std::map as rvalue?

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, stdmap, rvalue

I'm not sure if this is an error with my C++ syntax, or if this is something that cannot be accomplished at all.

I want to define a class that takes a std::map as a constructor argument. I then want to create an instance of that class by passing a "temporary" (appropriate to call this "rvalue"?) std::map. I.e. I do not want to create an lvalue std::map and then pass that to the constructor.

Can this be accomplished? I have tried the following (commented lines show failed attempts)

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    public:
        Test(std::map<int,char>& rMap)
        {
            std::map<int,char>::iterator iter;

            for (iter = rMap.begin(); iter != rMap.end(); ++iter)
            {
                mMap[iter->first] = mMap[iter->second];
            }
        }
        virtual ~Test(){}

    protected:
        std::map<int, char> mMap;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;

    //Test test({1,'a'});                   // Compile error.
    //Test test(std::map<int,char>(1,'a')); // Also compile error.
    //Test test(std::map<int,char>{1,'a'}); // Yet again compile error.

    return 0;
}
```

This is my compiler:

```
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
```

Compile errors can be posted upon request, but I'm not sure if they would be useful if my problem is syntactic.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `Test test(std::map<int, char>{{1, 'a'}});` with two sets of curly brackets?

Comment: @TimStraubinger - tried this upon your suggestion, but resulted in yet another compile error.

Comment: _What_ "compile error"?

Comment: Updated the question with the constructor taking reference-to-const, and also added the compile errors from each of my three failed attempts to create a Test.

Comment: Note that all your compile errors point to the same line. The errors have nothing to do with rvalues - you're trying to assign a const iterator to a non-const iterator.

Comment: I rolled back your edit as all 4 answers are addressing the original version of the question, and the new question has an entirely unrelated problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <map>

class Test {
public:
    Test(std::map<int,char> const& cMap)
    {
        std::map<int,char>::const_iterator iter;
        for (iter = cMap.cbegin(); iter != cMap.cend(); ++iter)
        {
            mMap[iter->first] = mMap[iter->second];
        }
    }
    virtual ~Test() { }
protected:
    std::map<int, char> mMap;
};

int main() {
    Test test(std::map<int,char>({{1,'a'}, {2, 'b'}}));
    return 0;
}
```

*Some* explanations:

1. You need `Test(T)`, `Test(const T&)` or `Test(T&&)` constructor if you want to pass temporary object (like `std::map<int,char>()`) into it. Don't forget what `T&&` constructors is used for. If in doubt do not use them.
2. If you work with `const std::vector/map/list/...` you can't use `.begin()` and `.end()` to iterate through elements -- use .**c**begin() and .**c**end(). Moreover it will become more easy with `auto`. Just try

   ```
   for (auto iter = rMap.cbegin(); iter != rMap.cend(); ++iter)
   ```

   instead

   ```
   std::map<int,char>::const_iterator iter;
   for (iter = rMap.cbegin(); iter != rMap.cend(); ++iter)
   ```
3. To initialize `std::map` use "double-bracket" initializers like `{{1,'a'}, {2, 'b'}}` -- `{{key, value}, {second_key, second_value}, ...}` this construction is available because

   1) `std::map` has this constructor:

   ```
   map( std::initializer_list<value_type> init,
        const Compare& comp = Compare(),
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
   // see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map
   ```

   2) inner braces `{1,'a'}` is interpreted as `value_type` constructor call. And `value_type` for `std::map<int, char>` is `std::pair<int, char>`.

P. S. don't forget that `std::map<int,char>()` and `std::map<int,char>{}` constructor calls are equal. That means you can drop front brackets: `std::map<int,char>({{1,'a'},{2,'b'}}) --> std::map<int,char>{{1,'a'},{2,'b'}}`

Comment: I like how your prose and your example say almost polar opposite things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, the question author wanted to accept r-value in constructor. My example solves author question but I'm still wondering does author understands where r-values meant to be used.

Comment: Would you say that this answer is likely to increase that understanding?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Okey. Okey. Take it easy. I fixed my answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't think any comments needed because code shows for itself. `const&` -- const reference, `const_iterator` `cbegin` `cend` -- work with `const&` and proper map costruction with "double brackets" `{{1,'a'}, {2, 'b'}}`

Comment: @slavanap Your method of creating a Test object worked for me. To answer your query, I do understand the concept to rvalues. This was a partially academic exercise for me to understand creating an rvalue std::map with extended initializer-lists, as you have done. Initializer-lists are straightforward enough with PODs and "simple" classes, but I guess I became discombobulated over where parentheses go and where braces go when creating a std::map in this manner. I'll chew over your solution, but I'd be happy if you have an textual explanation too.

Comment: Explain _why_ those things are needed/best/recommended. The OP wouldn't be asking if they knew already; the same goes for future visitors.

Comment: @StoneThrow if you think that you understand r-values, then try to understand difference between `std::move` and `std::forward` and what is "universal reference". I spent 2 hours with discussion on IRC channel to get that tiny difference. It's not that  easy, believe me! :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit added some explanations

Comment: @slavanap I wish you made an edit with comments though. It's a good coding style and you are here to help, after all

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit #TIL `to discombobulate`, thanks

Comment: _Now_ it's an answer.

Comment: Re #2, sure you can, you just get a `const_iterator` rather than an `iterator`. Read [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin)

Comment: & your PS has a non sequitur in it

Comment: Very helpful answer and discussion. Thank you slavanap and lightnessracesinorbin

Comment: `std::map` has a copy constructor. You should use it, instead of adding the elements in one by one.

Comment: @Barry the top question was not about it.

Comment: @slavanap Huh? I'm referring to the constructor that you wrote in `Test`. Just simply `Test(std::map<int,char> const& cMap) : mMap(cMap) { }`

Comment: @Barry, I just copied OP code. There's nothing wrong with it. Reread OP's question. You're point has its place but it is not related to the question.

Answer (score 6):

Do

```
Test(std::map<int, char> rMap) : mMap(std::move(rMap)) {}
```

or

```
Test(std::map<int, char>&& rMap) : mMap(std::move(rMap)) {}
```

or

```
Test(const std::map<int, char>& rMap) : mMap(rMap) {}
```

Temporary cannot bind to non const l-value reference.

And use it as

```
Test test({{1,'a'}});
Test test2({{1,'a'}, {2, 'b'}});
```

Comment: Okay. _Why?_ Not useful without explanation. Don't just code dump.

Comment: @Jarod42 If I went with option 1, what is the correct way to instantiate a Test object? I'm still having trouble with the syntax of creating an rvalue std::map.

Answer (score 4):

Yes but your constructor takes an lvalue reference. It must instead be a reference-to-`const`, or an rvalue reference.

Just like with any other type.

Comment: If I want to use a reference to const (as opposed to the rvalue reference), what is the correct syntax? After defining constructor Test(std::map<int,char> const& rMap), I'm still struggling with invoking this with an rvalue std::map instance.

Comment: @StoneThrow: What does "I'm struggling" _actually_ mean?

Comment: "struggling" here specifically means continued compile errors. Having changed constructor to Test(std::map<int,char> const& rMap), I still am not able to instantiate a Test object using any of the three methods in my main(). What is the correct syntax to _instantiate_ a Test object if its contructor took a reference-to-const?

Comment: As a secondary note: unless this problem can only be solved with an rvalue reference, I would like to solve it with the reference-to-const that you suggested.

Comment: @StoneThrow: Until you tell us _what those compilation errors are_, and _what your code looks like_, I don't understand how you expect us to help you fix them. "I'm struggling" and "continued compile errors" does not help us to help you.

Comment: Updated the question with the constructor taking reference-to-const, and also added the compile errors from each of my three failed attempts to create a Test. Thank you for your perseverance investigating this with me.

Comment: @StoneThrow you constucting std::map for an argument for you class wrong. Please, note the difference: your code `Test test(std::map<int,char>(1,'a'));` correct code `Test test(std::map<int,char>({{1,'a'}, {2,'b'}}));` <-- double brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(const std::map<int,char>& rMap) : mMap(rMap)
    {}
    Test(std::map<int,char>&& rMap) : mMap(std::move(rMap))
    {}
    virtual ~Test(){}
protected:
    std::map<int, char> mMap;
};
```

This provides two constructors: one which takes a `const` lvalue reference and copies its contents into `mMap` and one which takes an rvalue reference and moves its contents into `mMap`.  This allows you to construct a `Test` instance using either a named `std::map` or a temporary:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int,char> m{{1, 'a'}, {2,'b'}};
    Test t1{m};
    Test t2{{{1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'}}};
}
```

This lets you avoid unnecessary copies when you can, but still lets you make a copy of the `map` when you need to.

Comment: Surely the way to do that is a single overload that takes the map by value?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit People (e.g. Niebler) say that, but it'd be great if that didn't incur an extra move.

Comment: @Barry: A move is effectively free, even when it can't be optimised away (which is rare). Much better than repeating yourself unless you have some circumstance under which this is _really_ a problem.